# Monitoring memory on linux via system calls

Tags: linux, memory, monitor, mmap, strace

I have been looking around for a way to measure memory usage on Linux. I found out three main ways of doing it and I am not sure what should I use, therefore I am asking here for opinions.

1. It seems that the most widespread and maybe easier way of
   monitoring memory is to read /proc/pid/status and read the the
   appropriate field, `VmSize`, `VmData` or whatever. This is the way the
   programs ps, to, vmstat manage to colect this information(I mean,
   monitoring /proc/pid/...). This information will provide
   instantanous information.
2. I can call a fork followed by an exec to run the program I want
   to monitor and wait4 to get to fill an rusage structure. From there
   I can read the desired field. It seems though that in Linux, the
   wait4 does not fill memory fields in the rsusage structure, but only
   the cpu usage related fields. This is the way the time command gets
   its infortions.
3. I can change strace code, to keep track of all suceeding brk,
   mmap, munmap system calls, and sum up to get heap size. The
   difficult here would be decode all possible mmap arguments for read
   only, read|write, exec etc, and test return values to know if the
   system succeeded.

For 3), Do you think I can measure memory usage this way? Would that be too difficult? I have a good understanding of strace code, but I do not understand enough from memory, to know if this is possible.

Comment: Why not use the first approach? If the OS is already doing the instrumentation for you, why try and outguess it?

Answer (score 0):

If your program is only interested in memory allocations done using malloc(), you could have a look to mallinfo().

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, more precise information about memory maps are available thru `pmap` and with the `/proc/self/maps` or `/proc/1234/maps` file (where 1234 is the process id). Try `cat /proc/self/maps` to understand more.